# Only One Site Available Per Developer Org?

Tags: force.com-sites

I have a Vf page that I want to make as public site. I have used already site of salesforce for another page. It is not allowing me to create another site, In dev org I can create only 1 site.

How to make VF page as a public page without login into salesforce ?

Comment: You'll likely either need another dev org, or need to re-use your old force.com site to provide access to multiple pages. I don't believe theres anyway to increase the number of sites available to a developer org.

Comment: Throw it on a public community